# how to hide odoo action type buttons that have no name attributes?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to hide replenish button in product form and make it visible for a specific group
here is the button definition

```
<button string="Replenish" type="action"
                        name="%(action_product_replenish)d"
                        context="{'default_product_tmpl_id': id}"
                        groups="stock.group_stock_user"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '!=', 'product')]}"/>
```

I used xbath to add change the group attribute as below

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(action_product_replenish)d']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="groups">stock.group_stock_manager</attribute>
</xpath>
```

but I get this error

**raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)**
how can I do it dears ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost correct. Try prepending module name. For e.g. in `expr`, use `//button[@name='%(<module_name>.action_product_replenish)d']` instead.

As a side note, as @Dipen Shah said, you may want to use `attributes` instead of `replace` since the latter will remove other already defined attributes.

Comment: thanks Bro, <module_name> befrore id ref fixed this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the specific `group` then use with an `attribute` on button following:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(action_product_replenish)d']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">stock.group_stock_manager</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Or if you `replace` the button then you must have to re-declare that button until you are not able to replace having an error. Following code for `replace`:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(action_product_replenish)d']" position="replace">
    <!-- This way you replace it's behavior  -->
    <button string="Replenish" type="action"
        name="%(action_product_replenish)d"
        context="{'default_product_tmpl_id': id}"
        groups="Your groups"
        attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '!=', 'product')]}"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: sorry for intruding on the question but can the group be added to `<xpath>` or `<template>` sorry for again 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548218/how-to-load-css-based-on-group-odoo-13

Comment: thanks dear that's what i already did , and still have the issue