# How to load css based on group odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I want to load a different stylesheet based on user group (or if possible user selected company company)

This is my code

```
<odoo>
    <template id="id" name="your name" inherit_id="website.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': 1}</attribute>               

                <link href="/n_hesaby_subscription_manager/static/src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Thank you for your help

can the file be scss

Comment: As far as i know the assets should not have dynamic content because assets are delivered to the user regardless of state. To achieve what you want would mean to define your own asset group  that are loaded in addition to the normal asset group. You could have a look at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/13.0/addons/web_editor  it defines its own asset group thats loaded in addition to the normal backend and frontend asset groups.

Comment: @bigbear3001 Thank u for replying. can you please give me more info, point me to the part or give and example sorry but am lost

Comment: the problem is i never tried it myself i just discussed this with one of the odoo folks 2 years ago when there was a bug in odoo where someone added a t-if to a script tag in the assets. In 13.0 the web_editor.wysiwyg_iframe_editor_assets is an asset group that gets loaded only when you are editing in an iframe so thats were my investigation would start. But i don't know all the stuff to get it working just that the editor does the same thing you want (loading assets depending on if the user is a website editor).

Comment: The bug in the assets i'm talking about got introduced here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/23831/files#diff-0de0e205c360d6b061a2281ab3b9abcbR9
then was refactored:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/31704/files#diff-c7dab7f11ffa06829bbc6ac5c87a99a8R68
and finally fixed:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/31782/files#diff-0de0e205c360d6b061a2281ab3b9abcbR9

so i would not use t-if inside assets

Comment: what am Trying to do is change the odoo color/css based on the user group/comapny@bigbear3001

Comment: like a theme or something can be done another way then @bigbear3001

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216554/discussion-between-bigbear3001-and-moaz-mabrok).